# Excel: Finding row count between two specific values

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, row, vba

I need to indicate in column B the number of rows between where "Criteria Matched" is found in Col D and where "TRUE" is found in Col C.

Criteria Matched and True can occur multiple times, I am looking for the row count distance between the first True and Criteria matched, then the distance between the next two.. etc.

Any ideas? I am a VBA and Excel noob.

[image: Row Count Problem]

Comment: Have you tried writing any code?

Comment: I am not familiar with code :( Though I have bought a VBA beginners book and plan to start reading this afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

If both search terms occur only once in their respective columns, try

```
=match("Criteria Matched",D:D,0)-match(TRUE,C:C,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon the previous answer to account for multiple occurrences, you can put this formula in B1 and copy down as needed: =IF($C1=TRUE,MATCH("Criteria Matched",$D2:$D$300,0)-1,""). This gives a count of rows "between" the two values where  "TRUE" is followed by "Criteria Matched" as you stated. If you really meant rows "until", remove the -1 from the formula.

If you need a count between when any one follows the other, then this in B1: =IFERROR(IF($C1=TRUE,MATCH("Criteria Matched",$D2:$D$300,0)-1,IF($D1="Criteria Matched",MATCH(TRUE,$C2:$C$300,0)-1,"")),"")